# Elasticsearch REST API: search by particular field only

Tags: elasticsearch

When I perform search as bellow, I expect to find all tweets with text `hello people` (or at least one of this word).

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/tweet/_search?q=text:hello people'
```

While elastic is applying field (text) filter only to first word, and search second word across all other fields.
Obviously my results are among responses, but also there are a lot of data that I do not expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

You need to wrap your query string in ( ), such as:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/tweet/_search?q=text:(hello people)'
```